# How to create a PHP parseable input using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, input, submit

I'm creating an admin space for a local news company. The structure of an uploaded news is the following:

- title
- date
- picture
- text

They asked me to let them change the uploaded picture from the admin space, in case they uploaded a wrong image.
Therefore when a user clicks "EDIT EXISTING NEWS", the page displays the above mentioned parts (title, date, picture and text) in the appropriate input (text, textarea) and shows also the picture.

I created a little RECYCLE BIN icon under the picture, which if clicked, does the following:

- using AJAX replaces the displayed picture with a FILE INPUT.

However this newly created **input type="file" name="picture"** isn't viewable, parseable, processable after SUBMIT. Simply I can't view the $_POST["picture"], telling me it isn't set.

What can I do to be able to see it?

Please help!

Many thanks!

Huba

Comment: "using AJAX replaces the displayed picture with a FILE INPUT" - could you post this code as well.  We'll need more details to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data uploaded with `<input type="file" ... />` is not accessible through `$_POST`, but through `$_FILES` (even though it's received through a POST request). See [handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Many Many THX for both of you! The $_FILES resolved everything! I consider this article as CLOSED and RESOLVED! Thanks again...